# Взять цену с сайта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, парсер

Прошу подсказать как взять цену с сайта к примеру http://www.tinko.ru/p-249287.html? Использую такой код.

```html
(function($){
function ajaxStart(){
  $('#progress').show();
}
function ajaxStop(){
  $('#progress').hide();
}
function parserGo(){
  ajaxStart();
  var b = $.ajax('http://www.tinko.ru');
  b.done(function (d) {
    analysisSite(d);
    ajaxStop();

  });
  b.fail(function (e, g, f) {
    alert('Epic Fail');
    ajaxStop();
  })
}
function analysisSite(data){
  var res = '';
  $(data).find('div.min').each(function(){
   res+=$(this).text()+'=>'+$(this).attr('href')+'';
  })
  $('#resultbox').html(res);
}
$(function(){
  $('#progress').hide();
  $('#starter').click(parserGo);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Беру строку с ценой и еще к ней текст, который мне не нужен. Как получить только цифру?

Comment: Универсальных всемогутеров не существует, извините. Каждый сайт имеет индивидуальную структуру, а потому требует серьёзного допиливания используемых инструментов.

Comment: достаточно помочь с одним сайтом, дальше я смогу по аналогии распарсить отличные по структуре сайты.

Comment: А вы [соглашение о пользовании сайтом](http://www.tinko.ru/agreement) читали? Там написано: _Информация сайта ООО «ТД ТИНКО» защищена авторским правом и действующим законодательством о защите интеллектуальной собственности._ Вы спрашиваете, как бы вам поудобнее нарушить лицензионное соглашение, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: то есть я не имею права смотреть цены которые они вывешывают на сайте? Нет я не читал, не вижу ничего противозаконного если я поинтересуюсь их ценой...

Answer (score 3):

Пример, после получения строки с суммой:

```
var r, re,s,end;
s='13 990,00 i/шт'
re = /\D+/ig;
r = s.replace(re, '');
end = r.slice(0, -2);
document.write(end);
```

Comment: Это имеет право на жизнь. я так понимаю все это (13 990,00 i/шт) находится в элементе 'p' в котором есть текст 13 990,00 и элемент с классом span. Вот есть ли возможность без элемента с классом span вывести число?

Comment: @Михаил, можно все, как говорят: "В программировании все зависит только от времени и денег". В вашем случае от времени.

Comment: Я понял!) Благодарю!) как закончу регистрацию, поставлю отметку обязательно!